# Priority REST: Does not support OData parameter "$count"

Tags: priority-web-sdk

Does not support OData parameter "$count".
https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#count
It is very important parameter which helps to reduce time for requests.
Moreover, it should be supported if you declare that you are working on an OData protocol.
Requests:

> https://my.domain.com/odata/Priority/tabula.ini/demo/DOCUMENTS_D/$count
>
> https://my.domain.com/odata/Priority/tabula.ini/demo/DOCUMENTS_D?$count&$filter=CDES eq 'Some text'

(As usual) Return incorrect "500 Internal Server Error" error.
Is this issue are common for whole Priority REST ?
When you plan to add support of "count" parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the $count parameter is not implemented.
It is not mandatory by the Odata protocol specification to support the $count parameter
(on the Minimal and Intermediate Conformance Levels).
Maybe you can use $top parameter in some cases to limit the size of the result.

Regarding the 500 Server error, I suggest you add to the web.config file
the line

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

in the system.web section.
Then you may see a more informative error.

Comment: The parameter $count is a part of OData starting from v1. In my opinion, it refers to "Minimal and Intermediate Conformance Level" of support.
When you plan to add support of "count" parameter ?

Comment: As far as I know, There is no plan currently to add support for the $count operator.